# Can I power Canon 77D with an external power supply other than the official AC-E6N?

Tags: canon

The official power supply for the 77D is the AC-E6N. Unfortunately it is out of stock on all websites that I've checked, so I'm struggling to find an alternative solution.

Is there another adapter I can use for the camera, that's in stock somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous generic 'AC-E6N' power adapters available. The top selling one at amazon in the U.S. is about one-fifth the cost of the official Canon AC-E6N.

However, the 77D does not use the LP-E6N battery and thus does not use the AC-E6N. (The 7D and 7D Mark II, among many other Canon xD cameras where *x* is a single digit other than "1", use the LP-E6, LP-E6N, and the AC-E6.)

**The correct battery for the 77D is the LP-E17 and the corresponding AC adapter is the ACK-E18.**

There are also numerous generic 'ACK-E18' power adapters available, and the top selling one at amazon in the U.S. is also about one-seventh the cost of the official Canon ACK-E18.